# Can't output negative numbers with printf but echo works

Tags: bash, unix

Sorry if this is a stupid question with an obvious answer lying on some manpage. I couldn't find good info there.

There's this beginner practice problem where two, non-zero, integers are given and you need to write a script to print their sum, difference, product and quotient, each on a new line.

Sure there are extremely simple ways of doing this in one-line but here's what I ended up doing

```sh
read x
read y
printf "$(( "$x" + "$y" ))\n"
printf "$(( "$x" - "$y" ))\n"
printf "$(( "$x" * "$y" ))\n"
printf "$(( "$x" / "$y" ))\n"
```

While this works fine if x and y are positive and x is greater than y, I get an error when any of the operations should give a negative result (i.e. when either x or y is negative or x is less than y)

For example, if x is 50 and y is 20 I get

```sh
70
30
1000
2
```

But if x is 20 and y 50

```sh
70
./twon: line 3: printf: -3: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
1000
0
```

Similar if I try negative numbers, let x=-50 and y=20

```sh
./twon: line 3: printf: -3: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
./twon: line 4: printf: -7: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
./twon: line 5: printf: -1: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
./twon: line 6: printf: -2: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

However, if I substitute the `printf` command with an `echo -e`

```sh
read x
read y
echo -e "$(( "$x" + "$y" ))"
echo -e "$(( "$x" - "$y" ))"
echo -e "$(( "$x" * "$y" ))"
echo -e "$(( "$x" / "$y" ))"
```

everything works fine and I get all of the operations' results for any pair of integers.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The first argument to `printf` is a **format string**, not literal data. `printf '%s\n' "anything"` works with any value of `anything` (including values you can't reliably print with `echo`).

Comment: See the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which describes how to use `printf` as a replacement (and strongly recommends doing so). You'll see that the `printf` equivalent to traditional XSI `echo` (that being one that changes, say, `\t` to a literal tab) is `printf "%b\n" "$*"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ugh, can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot. mods feel free to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead :

```
printf '%s\n' "$(( x / y ))"
```

Comment: Why does this work? Why do you need to put quotes around arithmetic expansion in order to display negative values? Thank you for the solution.